# MS Access: How can I average a list of quantities on a report where the quantities are not zero?

Tags: ms-access, report, average, ms-access-2013

I have a report. This reports returns a lot of rows. One of the columns is `qty_req` (quantity required). I need to `AVG()` this column and put the value of the average at the bottom of the report. The problem is that sometimes some rows have a zero in this column. I want the average to exclude any rows where there is a zero. How can I accomplish this?

**What I've tried:** I tried using `DAvg` in the query but it made the query time enormous.

Comment: Zero = 0. This won't affect the sum, so why do you need to exclude them?

Comment: @Andre I'll make it more applicable. Editing now.

Comment: The overall point is that I need to do calculations on the `SUM` or `AVG` of the rows IF AND ONLY IF the `qty_req` column does not have a `0` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Avg()` ignores Null values.  So you can use an `IIf()` expression to swap Null for your zero values, and then base the `Avg()` on that `IIf()` expression.

Here is the Control Source for a text box in my report's footer:

```
=Avg(IIf([gainOrLoss]=0, Null, [gainOrLoss]))
```

`gainOrLoss` is a field in the report's Record Source.  And the text box displays the average of all those values which are neither zero nor Null.

Comment: This worked. I have a new question now, not sure if you would like me to post it as a new question or not. It's so similar to this though. If so, just say the word and I will. I now need to sum another column, `qty_issued`, based on whether or not the `qty_req` is zero. So `Sum([qty_issued])`, but if the `qty_req` column is zero, don't include that in the summation. How do I do this?

Comment: Ok I created it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747275/ms-access-how-can-i-take-the-average-of-a-column-and-ignore-the-rows-where-anot

Answer (score -1):

Well then you can't use a calculated `SUM()` or `AVG()` field, simple as that.
These functions always use all rows in the report.

You need `DSum()` or `DAvg()` to calculate it separately.

If that's too slow, you need to tackle this problem.

Comment: Right so how do I "tackle this problem"?