# Ms Access: How can I take the average of a column but ignore the rows where another column is 0?

Tags: ms-access, average, ms-access-2013

I have 2 columns, `qty_req` and `qty_issued` in a report. I need to find the average of the values in the `qty_issued` column. The problem is that sometimes the corresponding value of `qty_req` is 0. I need to take the average of the `qty_issued` column for only the rows where `qty_req` is **NOT** 0. How do I do this?

Spun off from my other question here: [MS Access: How can I average a list of quantities on a report where the quantities are not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744454/ms-access-how-can-i-average-a-list-of-quantities-on-a-report-where-the-quantiti/38746164?noredirect=1#comment64868010_38746164)

Comment: `SELECT AVG(qty_issued), qty_req FROM (SELECT qty_issued, qty_req from YourTableName WHERE qty_req <> 0) GROUP BY qty_req`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that in the *Control Source* of a text box on your report, you can take advantage of the fact that `Avg()` ignores Null values.

So, when `qty_req` <> 0, include `qty_issued` among the values which are averaged.  Otherwise use Null instead of the `qty_issued` value.

```
=Avg(IIf(qty_req <> 0, qty_issued, Null))
```

If you want to do it in a query instead ...

```
SELECT Avg(IIf(qty_req <> 0, qty_issued, Null)) FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: I added the query example because I saw the `GROUP BY` suggestions, and I don't think those will do what you want.  However, I don't see why you would want a separate query in your report anyway.

Comment: Which method is normally faster? In the report or in the query?

Comment: Test both and tell us!

Answer (score 0):

You would set the criteria in the query to not look at the qty_req that is 0:

```
SELECT Avg(MyTable.qty_issued) AS Avg_Issued
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.qty_req
HAVING MyTable.qty_req <> 0;
```